# Can't use tensorflow.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM or keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM in my Colab hosted runtime

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

When I tried to use either tensorflow.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM or keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM, I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by {{node cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNN}}with these attrs: [dropout=0, seed=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", is_training=true, seed2=0]
Registered devices: [CPU, XLA_CPU]
```

I am using the hosted runtime and I presume that supports GPU as well but I noticed the error message above shows there is no GPU. Not so sure what the problem is but any clue will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly request a GPU enabled runtime.

From the Runtime menu select "Change runtime type" then select GPU under "hardware accelerator":

[image]